# Removing Junk Character from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement in a case condition in one of the query which determines if a record is a pass or fail.

The condition is like below:

```
CASE
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 [-^+!#.,&''""():/-]%', [NAME1]) = 0 
        THEN 'Pass'
        ELSE 'Fail'
    END AS RESULTS
```

meaning, we are checking for any junk chars in the string, but there are some hidden chars in some of the strings between two words (in the space) like ex: U+A0 (got to know this from an online tool check)

Now, how do I include this check in the above condition which I have? I tried the COLLATE function which I saw in this group, but either I'm not using it correctly or its not working.

Could someone help me on how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). U+A0 is a non-breaking space, when I test with a string with/without it your case expression works.

Comment: select PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 [-^+!#.,&''""():/-]%', 'Lance Downs') This is giving me an o/p of 6. Let me know if this is what you are looking for @stu

Comment: +UA0 appears to be a code point in Unicode to represent 'non-breaking space' - frequently used by web-sites and introduced to databases when people copy/paste. Actually this is a two byte sequence of 00 A0 (hex); you can incorporate it in your pattern as in this example `select patindex('%B'+NCHAR(0x00A0)+'%', 'AB'+NCHAR(0x00A0)+'CD')` (returns 2)

Comment: @userMT all characters are Unicode code points. How many bytes each code point occupies depends on the encoding and collation of the data type that's storing them. It's a 2 byte sequence in `nchar`/`nvarchar`/`ntext` data types because those are typically UCS-2 encoding (or, differently, a UTF-16 encoding on databases using a Supplementary Characters collation). Unless you're using a UTF-8 encoding on `char`/`varchar`/`text` data types then `A0` only occupies a single byte, e.g.: `select cast('%B'+CHAR(0xA0)+'%' as varbinary(max));`
and `select cast('AB'+CHAR(0xA0)+'CD' as varbinary(max));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned trying `COLLATE`, but you didn't show specifically what your tried. Did you try something like `PATINDEX('%[^...]%', [NAME1] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)`? The Latin1_General_BIN collation forces pretty much an exact (extended-ASCII) compare.

I suspect your environment may be defaulting to some other collation that includes a lot of character equivalences, such as space ~= non-breaking space. That would also affect some of the character ranges you have in your pattern, such as alpha characters including the accented variants.

The following applies your pattern to a range of characters 0x20 - 0xFF and shows results both without and with the Latin1_General_BIN collation.

```
DECLARE @Pattern VARCHAR(100) = '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 [-^+!#.,&''""():/-]%'

SELECT CHARCODE, C, S, Result1, Result2, Result3
FROM ( -- Generate 32..255 (x20..xFF)
    SELECT CharCode = d1 * 16 + d2
    FROM (VALUES (2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15)) D1(d1)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15)) D2(d2)
) CC
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        C = CHAR(CC.CharCode),
        S = 'ABC' + CHAR(CC.CharCode) + 'XYZ'
) S
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        Result1 = CASE
            WHEN PATINDEX(@Pattern, S) = 0 
            THEN '----'
            ELSE 'Fail'
            END,
        Result2 = CASE
            WHEN PATINDEX(@Pattern, S COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI) = 0 
            THEN '----'
            ELSE 'Fail'
            END,
        Result3 = CASE
            WHEN PATINDEX(@Pattern, S COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) = 0 
            THEN '----'
            ELSE 'Fail'
            END
) R
ORDER BY CC.CharCode
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90715615f1f8f8b4bc45b13f05be41ca). The interesting results start at character code 128 (0x80).